# PySpark to remove extra pipe from each column data using df.expand method

Tags: pyspark

I have a raw data as follows:

```
| col_0|               col_1|         col_2|   col_3|   col_4|      col_5|               
col_6|  col_7|     col_8|col_9|   col_10|col_11| col_12|col_13|col_14|     col_15|     
col_16|col_17|              col_18|        col_19|        col_20| col_21|
 +------+--------------------+--------------+--------+--------+-----------+------------- 
 -------+-------+----------+------+---------+------+-------+------+------+-----------+-- 
 ---------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
 ||2022|||4061520221505841...||r0014256510 |||DILLARD| DANIEL|||C00000935|||[24T 
 Contribution]|||Z9500||08/29/2021|    35||HIDALGO||  |TX|||78557||  |DP|| 
 |24T|||C00401224|||C00000935||   |M|||202205149504021121|||NOT EMPLOYED|||NOT 
 EMPLOYED|||Rept ||
 ||2022|||4061520221505841...||r0015503614 ||  |WHITE| SCOTTO|||C00633404|||[24T 
 Contribution]|||Z9500||08/29/2021|    15||YONKERS||  |NY|||10701||  |PI|| 
 |24T|||C00401224|||C00633404||   |M|||202205149507911003|||NOT EMPLOYED|||NOT 
 EMPLOYED|||Rept ||
```

As it is evident that in each row I have got extra "|" in each cell. And I want to remove them. Ultimately I want a clean dataframe separated by a single "|".

One way to achieve this using `regexp_extract`. Below is the code snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('test_col_0',F.regexp_extract('col_0','|',0))
```

For loop is not working it seems.

```
for c in df.columns:
  df = df.withColumn('test_'+c,F.regexp_extract(c,'|',0))
```

Hence the above approach has three issues:

1. I have to create additional 21 columns manually. Can we use a For loop?
2. There will be many columns created with complete blank. Eg. if we try `col_0` then it would create a blank columns. Can we ensure that we drop the blank columns?
3. Many columns would have no header at all!! Can we ensure to put a header in those columns that would have value but no header.

Is there any better way to get a clean dataframe? Ideally like below:

```
    |col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10|col_11| 
    col_12|col_13|col_14|col_15|col_16|col_17|col_18|col_19|col_20|col_21|col_22|
 +------+--------------------+--------------+--------+--------+-----------+------------- 
 -------+-------+----------+------+---------+------+-------+------+------+-----------+-- 
 ---------+------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
 |2022|4061520221505841|r0014256510|DILLARD|DANIEL|C00000935|[24T 
 Contribution]|Z9500|08/29/2021|35|HIDALGO|TX|78557|DP|24T|C00401224|C00000935| 
 M|202205149504021121|NOT EMPLOYED|NOT EMPLOYED|Rept|
```

Any clue on this. Can we think of `df.expand()`? But in that case how to provide the value of n?